# Should the manifest file of a hosted Firefox OS app live on the same domain?

Tags: firefox-os

Should the manifest file of a hosted Firefox OS app live on the same domain?
I'd like to put it on a CDN together with the rest of the static files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it should be served from the same origin. That is part of the security model of hosted apps and it is there to prevent abuse of your app. Take a look at [manifest page on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Apps/Developing/Manifest):

> ... the paths must be served from the same origin as the app